# Getting now() from database server in Laravel 5 to get around AWS clock drift

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I'm building a platform where precise time sync is critical (+/- 0.01 sec). Based on my (admittedly limited) understanding of AWS, it looks like clock drift between multiple server instances could become a real problem. However, I've been told RDS will not suffer from clock drift even as it scales up. As a result, I'm planning to use RDS when we go live and am trying to always pull now() with a database query instead of just using Carbon::now() (which would pull time from the Apache server). So I guess the preliminary question is: have I missed anything? Is that going to work? Is there a better approach that I've ignored?

Assuming my approach is correct, I'm trying to clean up the following:

```
$currentTime = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT NOW()'));
```

First off, that just looks messy and I'm sure there's a cleaner way. Second, instead of giving me the timestamp, it's returning an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [NOW()] => 2016-05-04 14:03:49
        )
)
```

I tried using ->first() and ->get(), but neither worked (both produce errors). How should I be handling this?

Comment: If I do the following, I get the output desired, but it still looks surprisingly messy:

    $serverTimeArray = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT NOW(3) AS now'));
    $serverTime = $serverTimeArray[0]->now;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a trickier deal than I originally anticipated. Laravel uses PDO to connect to MySQL. Though MySQL now supports DATETIME with up to 6 places of precision after the decimal, PDO does not support fractions of a second in DATETIME (yeah, "WTF?" is the right response). To retrieve and store data with the precision I'm after, I needed to change gears and use Unix time format (seconds since 1/1/1970). I'm storing that in the database as a DECIMAL(18,3) column to give me room for the millisecond precision I was after.

The code section I described above is now:

```
$serverTimeArray = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP(3)) AS now'));
$serverTime = $serverTimeArray[0]->now;
```

This actually makes a lot of my time manipulations (add/subtract time) quite a bit easier.

Seems to be working, though I now have a new, unrelated issue I might need to post a different question about...

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, you're incorect about clock drift being a problem on AWS. It's nothing to do with AWS.  Server clocks drift.  That's why you should always install `ntpd` on *any* server, because that problem effectively takes care of itself when you do. (How do you suppose the RDS clock stays accurate?)  Install `ntpd`, always, always, always, on our servers.

Second, `NOW()` has a margin of error of +/- 0.500 seconds, by definition.  Really, it's more like +0/-0.999999, since it can never actually show later than the current time... but your original solution here does not give you what you need, in any event... However, there is something to be said for having a single authoritative time source, and the database is probably the best candidate.  If the RDS machine is MySQL 5.6 or higher, consider `SELECT NOW(3)` for milliseconds or `SELECT NOW(6)` for microseconds.

Also, if you need an authoritative monotonic counter for determining conclusively whether one event occurred before another, investigate `UUID_SHORT()`, which is a 64 bit counter that increments by 1 every time you call it.  It will also jump forward each time the database server is rebooted, but as long as the database server clock is correct each time the server starts, it will never go backwards.

Comment: That's very good feedback. Precision to the actual time is not that necessary, but having a single authoritative time source (as you put it) is critical. NOW(3) sounds like the right answer to me. Now I just need to figure out the Laravel syntax piece.

Comment: Try aliasing the column... `SELECT NOW(3) AS server_time`.

Comment: Aliasing the column doesn't fix the issue of getting a class/array returned. It just changes the "NOW()" label in the returned array.